# Other stacks should be referenced on wiki and off-topic questions

Tags: feature-request, support, community-wiki

### Problem:

There is a huge amount of off-topic questions that gets unanswered. Questions are shut closed, very often without further explanation.

### Solution:

I suggest we make a simple guideline for redirecting questions to their respective correct stack exchange page. It could be as simple as a wiki list.

It's a small effort that would greatly help users.

---

## Examples:

#### As Is:

- Q: Keras classifier won't converge. [Closed - Off Topic]
- Q: Where can I find a dataset for whales? [Closed - Off Topic]
- Q: I get errors when converting Pandas dataframe.  [Closed - Off Topic]

#### To-Be:

- Q: Keras classifier won't converge. [Closed - Off Topic] - **Try asking Data Science**
- Q: Where can I find a dataset for whales? [Closed - Off Topic] - **Try asking Dataset exchange**(??)
- Q: I get errors when converting Pandas dataframe.  [Closed - Off Topic] - **Try asking Stack Overflow**

### Wiki Example:

Other useful wikis:

- [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

  - Examples:

    - I get errors when converting Pandas dataframe
    - ...
- [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

  - Examples:

    - Keras classifier won't converge.
    - ...

---

## My questions:

Does it make sense?

Do we have already something like this?

How can we start?

Answer (score 2):

We tried to specify in [our on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) examples of questions that would be off-topic here (see the section "Off-topic"), but we didn't provide an extensive list of types of questions that would be off-topic. I think we could indeed create a meta-post with a list of all types of questions that would be off-topic, but I am not sure if it's worth it, as the on-topic page should already be quite clear. Let me know what isn't clear enough by reading the on-topic page, so that we can clarify that.

Comment: Great to see there is already such a page! In my opinion, it's too big. (Estimated reading time: 4 minutes, 51 seconds. Contains 972 words). It should be more compact, or more structured (like using tables), more organized (using sub-bullets and sub-headers), or even using emojis (❌,✅) for easy, fast visual clues.

Comment: @AndreGoulart Yes, we can definitely improve the structure of the page.

Comment: I just took a look—been a while.  I parsed that page in 30 seconds, and could easily identify what section would contain the info I might be looking for.  Reading carefully, per Andre's timing, is another matter.  (My sense is people fall into two categories "read the manual" or "don't read the manual", and tech will always have both.  I'm the latter b/c I prefer to learn systems by observing and poking at them;)